# Deploying Web Forms and Asp.net MVC Application in one folder on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have Two different solution one is on Asp.net MVC and another one Asp.net , now my concern is how to deploy these two application on IIS in a single root. and all page should work. please help me. thanks

Comment: By "Asp.net", do you mean "webforms" (containing .aspx pages)?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about where the various solutions should end up? Could you install each in a separate subfolder? (if not, why?)

Comment: while publishing first app created one folder inside that folder created on more folder ,in that folder i have published second application. now same folder i am publishing on IIS. on IIS i have converted sub folder into application .am i going correct way?

Comment: yes Asp.net means webforms

Comment: i mean both the application should work in a single application

Comment: Webforms & mvc can exist in same web application project. You can also deploy to same IIS web app in that way